# PyQGIS read data from serial/COM ports

Tags: pyqgis, serial

I'd like to read data (from a device connected to the serial port) in QGIS using Python. Its not a GPS device; it is an AIS receiver so the QgsGPS tools obviously won't work.

I have got as far as;

```
QgsGPSDetector.availablePorts()
```

Which does appear to recognise the device;

```
[(u'localhost:2947:', u'local gpsd'), (u'\\\\.\\COM11', u'COM11:')]
```

I understand that serial/pyserial library is not included in the PyQGIS environment. If it was I think I could figure it out easily.

Any suggestions how to write a short script to read raw data from the serial/COM ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my issue in the following manner:

Installed pyserial at the Command Line using:

```
pip install serial
```

Once I verified the package was successfully installed (by running a Python session and typing 'import serial') I then had to ensure the package was installed in the Pycharm project interpreter. This is done manually in Pycharm as follows:

Pycharm>File>Settings>Project>Project Interpreter>

Scroll down the list of packages and double click serial. Then in the next window simply click "install package". I followed this up with a reboot and it worked fine since then.
Note: This worked for QGIS v3.0